# c# multi threading for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop

I'm pretty new into thread programming. I'm actually developping some kind of meta search engine and i need an application that parses webpages every second.

In my application i have a function that parses the wanted webpage for ie: go_parse("http://www.google.com/page/1);

What i want to do is when the function has finished to parse page 1 it parses the page 2, etc..but i'm a bit confused on how to do this.

i have to make a loop that launch the go_parse function 50 times at least (page 1 to 50).

Hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

With the TASK function i could get it work :

```
public void ProcessNextPage(int page)
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            go_parse("http://www.google.com" + searchForm.Text + "/"+page+"/");
        });
        t.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (label2.Text != "Stopped")
            {
                page++;
                SetTextBoxText(page.ToString(), textBoxPage, false);
                ProcessNextPage(page);
            }
        });
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "Started";
        ProcessNextPage(int.Parse(textBoxPage.Text));
    }
```

Thanks all

Comment: What's the relation to multithreading? Are the pages parsed in parallel? You might want to look into **the producer consumer queue pattern**.

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using? if .Net 4.0 look into Task, and ContinueWith

Comment: Well in the future i'd like to have something like 5 pages parsed in parallel (depending on ressources) but for the moment just 1 after 1 would be a good start. Like you said the queue system is what i'm looking for.

Yes i use .net 4

Comment: If you need it done serially (1 by 1), all you need is a simple `for` loop.

Comment: the for loop freeze my application. I really need something that waits until it's finished to go into the second loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using C# 4.0, you can use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), its [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) method, and `List<T>` or `Queue<T>`, or `Stack<T>` of pages to process.

Here I use, say `Stack<T>`.

So somewhere we have `stack` of all pages to process

```
public void ProcessNextPage() {

   if(stack.Count == 0) //INFINIT LOOP BREAK CONDITION
        return;

   var pageToProcess = stack.Pop();
   Task.StartNew(t=> {
       /*DO SOMETHING WITH pageToProcess*/
   }).ContinueWith(a=>processNextPage()); //ON COMPLETE, CALL MYSELF (RECURSION)
}
```

This is just a basic idea, you, naturally, should change  and architect it in the way that it better fits your needs.

Comment: Why do you prefer `Stack<T>` over `Queue<T>` in this case?

Comment: Well, because just feeling (push) and getting (pop) seems *to me* more simple solution in this case, then operate on indices. Just a matter of choice.

Comment: A queue doesn't operate on indices, it has similar methods as pop and push (queue and tryDequeue), only it is FIFO instead of LIFO (stack), which seems more logical to me personally in this case.

Comment: If you use `Stack` or `Queue` then you need to lock access to them, because they're not designed to be used by multiple concurrent threads.  Better yet would be to use a `ConcurrentQueue` or a `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: @Tigran based on [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123868/c-sharp-multi-threading-for-loop#comment19551051_14123868) It looks more like the question is how do you perform a long running task without blocking the UI.

Comment: @ConradFrix: instead based on question, that states "What i want to do is when the function has finished to parse page 1 it parses the page 2, etc..but i'm a bit confused on how to do this.". I understand that OP wants just parse pages *one after another* in simple chain (always in multithreading, naturally)

Comment: Thanks tigran and rotem, i managed to make it with TASK

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did something like this. Basically in short I made a class with a que, Which holds a list of items to be processed. Than I started a new thread with a processing class which goes through the que and processes these one by one through a loop.

If no items are in the que the processor waits again else the next item from the que is taken.

In this way the application creating the new items to be handled stays running seperate and without interference of the processing.

Somewhat like this from my memory:

```
private CustomQueClass queClass = new CustomQueClass();

Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
  new ThreadStart(() =>
  {
      CustomProcessClass processClass = new CustomProcessClass(queClass);
  }
));
backgroundThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a producer-consumer relationship.  The `BlockingCollection` class is *perfect* for these situations.  By default it will use a `ConcurrentQueue`, which is what you'll want.  Just create the queue, create as many worker threads as you want that each can use `GetConsumingEnumerable` to take items until they're done, and one or more producers adding items to the queue.